# Python - If given dictionary create a list of keys in order of the values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like the below.

```
ex1_pattern = {'ex':0,'country':1,'dow':2,'hod':3,'adx':4,'vid1':5}
```

I would like to create a lists of the keys e.g.

```
ex1_pattern.keys()
```

but..I would like the list to be in the order of the ranks. e.g.:

```
[ex,country,dow,hod,adx,vid1]
```

What is the most time efficient means to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sorted(ex1_pattern, key=ex1_pattern.get)
```